# Java 10: Axis 1.4 SOAP Service - Still possible to WSDD?

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, axis

In my web app I have a soap service which is unfortunately still created with AXIS 1.4. I'm trying to port my app to Java 10, where AXIS 1.4 is not working so well anymore.

When I try to create a server-config.wsdd file to deploy the service in Tomcat, the actual webservice is missing. Only default AdminService and Version are contained. This is how i create the wsdd in my ant script:

```
<java classpathref="classpath" classname="org.apache.axis.utils.Admin">
    <arg value="server"/>
    <arg value="../src/de/aedsicad/vermunterlagenportal/portaladapter/webservice/deploy.wsdd"/>
</java>
```

Does anyone know if there is a workaround to make this work with Java 10?

We try to get rid of Axis and use JAX-WS instead. Does anyone know if a service deployed by JAX-WS is still working with AXIS generated CLient stubs?